# Searching elements in an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, stdint

I want to search the index of the element in array days[] of uint8_t type which has next-to-next elements of 0x2 and 0x3 using a variable of type uint16_t and print the index value of the element '0x2'. I have assigned 'uint16_t search = 0x23' but I am not sure if that will work

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    uint8_t days[5] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5};
    uint8_t *ptr = days;
    uint16_t search = 0x23;
    for(uint16_t i=0;i<5;i++){
        if (*(ptr+i) == search){
            printf("%d", i);
            break;
        }else{
            printf("not found at %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read two consecutive uint8 elements of array as uint16? If yes, you must be carreful not to trigger UB. Moreover acorrectness would depend on endianess

Comment: yes, I want to read two consecutive uint8_t elements as uint16_t.

Comment: OT: `ptr` is usless, just replace with `*(days+i)` or even better with `days[i]` which is the idiomatic way.

Comment: Just do be sure: what output do you expect for `search = 0x34`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to search `0x23` and not `0x0203`? Could `days` contain values larger than `0x9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to search the uint8 array in pairs as uint16, you need to cast the pointer of the array from uint8 to uint16 before the comparison. Following is how the code should look like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t days[5] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5};
    uint8_t *ptr =  days;
    uint16_t search = 0x0302;
    for(uint16_t i=0;i<4;i++){
        if (*((uint16_t *) (ptr+i) ) == search){
            printf("%d", i);
            break;
        }else{
            printf("not found at %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I am casting the `(uint16_t *)` the pointer that was incremented as `uint8_t` with the `(ptr+i)` in order to travel trough the array in steps of `uint8_t`

Also note that I had lowered the loop to 4 times instead of 5, since by converting the last element of the array to `uint16_t` you will get outside of the boundaries of the array.

Finally, the value you are searching should be `0x0302` not `0x23`. First because the `0x03` and `0x02` are the values that will be stored in the `uint8`, and second, since due to `endianness`  of the CPU, they will be in opposite order in the memory when converted to `uint16_t`

> Note: When using cast you should be certain how the cast will be interpreted, meaning not to overrun the boundaries of the variables, otherwise you might cause segmentation faults, or even silent problems which will lead to an undefined behavior of your program.

Comment: You can add a note that in general such a cast could trigger UB due to strict-alising-rules. However, in this case `uint8_t` is likely an alias for `unsigned char` that can alias with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
  uint8_t days[5] = { 0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5 };
  uint16_t search = 0x23;

  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {             // 4 not 5 because of days[i + 1] below
    uint16_t value = (days[i] << 4) | days[i + 1];

    if (value == search)
    {
      printf("%d", i);
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("not found at %d\n", i);
    }
  }
```